# Color coding numbers in Python similar to Excel conditional formatting

Tags: python, html, css, numbers, conditional-formatting

Is there a module or any workarounds in Python to color code numbers from 0 to 100 going from red to green? I'm trying to better visualize a score by changing the font color based on the number but don't want to reinvent the wheel. Thought I could find myself 100 different colors and make a dictionary out of it but wanted to ask the community in advance. Many thanks.

NOTE: I am using Python, Flask, and HTML. I need a simple function/module that I can plug a number into to output a corresponding color in hex.

Comment: Is your required output strictly html?

Comment: Yes, I am using Python, Flask, and HTML. But I just need a function that I can plug a number into to output a corresponding color in hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try to separate the colors into 10 buckets instead of 100, then make a list out of it.

```
colors = ["#first", "#second", "#third", ..., "#tenth"]
```

Then, write a simple function to assign the number to the corresponding color.

```
def pick_color(num):
    if num in range(0, 10):
        return colors[1]
    elif num in range(10, 20):
        return colors[2]
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, you can use the following code to get the picture attached. You will need Pandas, Numpy for rounding, and you *may* need Matplotlib as well.

`(np.round(df.corr().iloc[:-1, :], 6).style.format({})
 .background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn', low=.4, high=.4))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need for this can be found in the `matplotlib`.

https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/color/named_colors.html